# Ruby range.reduce with hash accumulator

Tags: ruby, hash, range

I have this method

```
def heights
  (60..68).reduce({}) { |h, i| h.merge!( { %(#{i/12}'#{i%12}") => i } ) }
end
```

it returns a hash of heights

```
{
  "5'0\"" => 60, "5'1\"" => 61, "5'2\"" => 62,
  "5'3\"" => 63, "5'4\"" => 64, "5'5\"" => 65,
  "5'6\"" => 66, "5'7\"" => 67, "5'8\"" => 68
}
```

That's what I want. However, I don't like using the `merge!` method. I'd much rather use the `hash[key] = value` syntax for assignment:

```
def heights
  (60..68).reduce({}) { |h, i| h[%(#{i/12}'#{i%12}")] = i }
end
```

But this code throws errors. I know that with reduce, in your pipes you can name your accumulator and element.

I also understand that

```
sum = 0
(1..5).each { |i| sum += i }
```

is equivalent to

```
(1..5).reduce(0) { |sum, i| sum + i }
```

So why doesn't this

```
hash = {}
(1..5).each { |i| hash[i.to_s] = i }
```

work the same as

```
(1..5).reduce({}) { |hash, i| hash["#{i}"] = i }
```

Comment: @EddeAlmeida The string format is fine. `%()` is just another way to create a string.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida The double quote is part of the string, not the ending of the string. In order to represent height in feet as a string you need `5'6"` which can be written in ruby as `"5'6\""` or `%(5'6")`

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry.

Comment: Using `%Q(...)` instead of just `%(...)` might be clearer. I don't see the `%(...)` form that often in the wild but that might be just me.

Comment: It's tangential to your question, but you could also write `(60..68).map { |i| ["%d'%d\"" % i.divmod(12), i] }.to_h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block in `reduce` should return new accumulator. In your case

```
(1..5).reduce({}) { |hash, i| hash["#{i}"] = i }
```

block returns `i`, which is an integer, so on the second iteration you will try to call `[]` on an integer. What you need it this:

```
(1..5).reduce({}) { |hash, i| hash["#{i}"] = i; hash }
```

Comment: Great to know. This was the answer. Thank you.

Comment: IMHO `each_with_object` wins here in terms of semantics, since it was pretty much exactly added for this use case.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of `reduce`:

```
(60..68).each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[%(#{i/12}'#{i%12}")] = i }
```

`enumerable.each_with_object(obj) { ... }` returns `obj` so you don't need the artificial-feeling `; h` in the block that you'd need with `reduce`.

Note that the order of the arguments to the block is different than with `reduce`.

Comment: You're also right, rubocop gave me the same suggestion. But Victor was first. Unless we can have two correct answers, I'll give him the win. Hope that's ok 

Comment: @CruzNunez No worries, I have an excess of points :) I tend to use `reduce`/`inject` when feedback is central to what I'm doing and `each_with_object` when I'm iterating with a sidecar, adding an "artificial" return value to the block suggests that I'm doing the latter.

Comment: Consider writing the block `{ |i, h| h["%d'%d\"" % i.divmod(12)] = i }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Or even `h[%Q{%d'%d"} % i.divmod(12)]` if you're really into percents but that might be a bit too close to line noise.